# Error with Video capturing code

Tags: c#, video-capture

I'm trying to go through the source code given at 
http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/608057-capturing-video-webcam but when i try to copy and paste in my project its showing error saying that

> Error 1   Inconsistent accessibility:
>   parameter type
>   'View_Box.WebCamCapture.WebcamEventArgs'
>   is less accessible than delegate
>   'View_Box.WebCamCapture.WebCamEventHandler'

What exactly is the problem with my code?

Below is the code snippet which I'm trying to compile and I have also highlighted the line where the error is occurring with start arrow and end arrow.

```
    [System.Drawing.ToolboxBitmap(typeof(WebCamCapture), "CAMERA.ICO")] // toolbox bitmap
    [Designer("Sytem.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner,System.Design", typeof(System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesigner))] // make composite


    public class WebCamCapture : System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;

        // property variables
        private int m_TimeToCapture_milliseconds = 100;
        private int m_Width = 320;
        private int m_Height = 240;
        private int mCapHwnd;
        private ulong m_FrameNumber = 0;

        private class WebcamEventArgs
        {
            public Image WebCamImage;
        }


        // global variables to make the video capture go faster
        private WebCamCapture.WebcamEventArgs x = new WebCamCapture.WebcamEventArgs();
        private IDataObject tempObj;
        private System.Drawing.Image tempImg;
        private bool bStopped = true;

        // event delegate
  -->Error in the below line
     public delegate void WebCamEventHandler(object source, WebCamCapture.WebcamEventArgs e);
  <--
        // fired when a new image is captured
        public event WebCamEventHandler ImageCaptured;

        #region API Declarations

        #region Camera API Constants
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the ans for my question...

---

**Solution**

The class WebcamEventArgs, it was private earlier so I changed into public. Now everything works fine ;)